# Hide <input> after .show()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I hope you can help me with this beacuse I'm new to coding.
I started to code myprofile/editprofile page.
As you can see in this picture

[Username and Password edit PICTURE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btlBN.png)

I made these 2 icons next to Name and Email to open these 2 inputs on click

```
<input type="text" id="edit_user"  style="display:none;" placeholder="New name." />
<div class="edit_hover_class"><b><?= $user['name'];  ?> </b><a><img onClick="show1()" src='images/edit-icon.png' /></a></div>
<input type="text" id="edit_pw" name="password"  style="display:none;" placeholder="New email." />
<div class="edit_hover_class"><?= $user['email'];  ?><a><img onClick="show2()" src='images/edit-icon.png' /></a></div>
```

This is script to show input

```
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('edit_user').style.display = "block";
}

function show2() {
  document.getElementById('edit_pw').style.display = "block";
}
```

How i can hide them on another click.
[Click icon to hide()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKtMM.png)

Comment: Use jquery instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery .toggle() function. Its simple...

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
function show1(){
  $( "#edit_user" ).toggle();
};
function show2(){
  $( "#edit_pw" ).toggle();
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```js
function show1()
    {
     //getting display of input type
    var d=document.getElementById('edit_user').style.display;   
    if(d=="block"){
     document.getElementById('edit_user').style.display="none";
     } 
    else{           
     document.getElementById('edit_user').style.display="block";
     }
    }
function show2()
    {
      //getting display of input type
      var d=document.getElementById('edit_pw').style.display;    
      if(d=="block"){
       document.getElementById('edit_pw').style.display="none";
       } 
      else{             
       document.getElementById('edit_pw').style.display="block";
      }
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="edit_user"  style="display:none;" placeholder="New name." />
<div class="edit_hover_class"><b>example</b>
    <a><img onclick="show1()" src='images/edit-icon.png' /></a>
</div>
<input type="text" id="edit_pw" name="password"  style="display:none;" placeholder="New email." />
 <div class="edit_hover_class">example
  <a><img onclick="show2()" src='images/edit-icon.png' /></a>
 </div>
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: your welcome .Please tick the answer if you find it helpful.Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to toggle functions:

```
function toggle1() {
   if(document.getElementById('edit_user').style.display !== 'block'){
      document.getElementById('edit_user').style.display = "block";
   }else{
      document.getElementById('edit_user').style.display = "none";
   }
}

function toggle2() {
   if(document.getElementById('edit_pw').style.display !== 'block'){
      document.getElementById('edit_pw').style.display = "block";
   }else{
      document.getElementById('edit_pw').style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

In this way the button will always show/display depending on the element state.